# Difference between Diffuse Optical Tomography and Optical Tomography

Tags: imaging

What are there the differences between these two modalities?

- [Diffuse Optical Tomography (DOT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_optical_imaging)
- [Optical Tomography (OT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Tomography)

Are there forms of OT that are not DOT?